# Searching list for substring: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, string, substring

I am trying to search through a list of links for a substring contained within some of the links. The list is made up of strings.

eg. "team.asp?league=sweden&stats=10-elfsborg" and searching for the string 'team'.

If I do `if any("team" in i for i in links): print('True')`, I get the result of 'True'.

If I want a list of all the matches, searching using `matches = [i for i in links if "team" in i]` gives me the error `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` when I do `print(matches)`.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Edit: Using BeautifulSoup, this is the way I am creating the list

`for link in soup.find_all('a'): links.append(link.get('href'))`

Comment: In the second snippet, either `i` or `teams` is `None`. You'll need to do some debugging to find out why. Most likely `find` from Beautiful Soup (assuming that's what you're using) wasn't able to find the element you wanted.

Comment: If I get the True result previously, why doesn't the second search find the same elements and create a list of those found?

Comment: I'm going to guess because `any` mixed with a generator expression (like you have) has early-exit behavior: it doesn't necessarily iterate over the entire collection unless it needs to. If it exits before it runs into an `i` that is `None`, it won't cause an error. You can test this by changing the first snippet to `if any(["team" in i for i in links]):`. The list comprehension (`[]`) is strict, causing it to lose part of the early-exit behavior, and should cause an error if I'm right.

Comment: Ah I see! It's a pretty big list and there must have been a NoneType somewhere in there that I didn't see, thanks!